# Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nuget-package

I tried to Install-Package `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`, but it throws this error:

> **Install-Package : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Pre
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio does this happen in? [Nuget error “Object reference not set to an instance of an object” while installing Entityframework 7 from Package Manager Console in VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763583/nuget-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-while-install/30070093).

Comment: Just to add to Andrew's Comment as well. What version of Dot net are you using. Make sure the version of dot net you are using is compatible with the version of the Nuget package you are using. I also would agree, use Visual Studio 17 or greater.

Comment: Andrew morton and akasoggybunz  thank you very much i solve my error by activation Microsoft and .NET source